# Refresh web page with Google assistant

Tags: google-assistant, google-voice-actions

Is there a command to make it refresh the web page currently shown in the browser on my phone? I tried multiple variations of "Hey Google ... Refresh the web page" but it instead shows me search results or opens Wikipedia. Argh. Want this to refresh it when I have dirty hands, so no touching, must be just voice.

Comment: I don't know if Google Assistant can refresh the web page or not since it must interact with the app directly, but [Voice Access](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/topic/6151842) accessibility can do this by saying e.g. "(Tap) More - (Tap) Refresh" on Chrome, if this is an acceptable workaround.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, that's acceptable. Didn't know that exists and had to turn it on first, and it keeps misunderstanding me most of the time, but it works.

Comment: @AndrewT. Should I broaden the question to more than Google assistant solutions (if I understand correctly, Voice Access isn't part of assistant).

Comment: I think so, since if I understand the situation correctly, what you actually want is to use voice command, not necessarily Google Assistant?

Answer (score 0):

[This article from ComputerWorld](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3612893/chrome-android-voice-commands.html) seems to indicate that you can say "Reload" on the *new* Google Assistant on Pixel 4 and up. Fair warning, I tried this on my Pixel 8 Pro though, and I was unable to get it to work for me.

> All right, fair warning: The rest of these commands are connected specifically to that "new" Assistant we were just talking about. Google had originally said that would be making its way to more Android devices sometime in 2020, but as far as I'm aware, it's still for some reason available only on those aforementioned Pixel phones. So unless you've got one of those devices (or your non-Pixel phone is a lucky exception to the rule), these remaining options probably won't work for you.
>
> For those of us in the Pixel-4-and-up camp, though, some especially powerful browser-manipulating possibilities are out there and just waiting to be used. And I don't know about you, but I had completely forgotten about all of them up until just now.
>
> So refresh your noggin with me, you silly, silly sea fish. To start, while viewing any site within Chrome on your phone, make yourself a mental note that you can hop around the browser by bringing up Assistant and saying any of the following phrases:
>
> 1. Go back
> 2. Go forward
> 3. Reload
> 4. Bookmark this page

As a (bad) workaround, you could ask the Assistant to open the same URL of the page you're on, although this admittedly works best for simply-accessed pages (such as facebook.com or reddit.com, where the content you're after is at an easily requestable URL).